# Animation not working while using Vector3.Lerp in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm creating an FPS Game in which I have a GunController Script... Which has DetermineAim() Method, basically a "scope In" function. I also have an Idle animation. So the problem is both Aim and Animation are not working together. If I add animation then the DetermineAim() stops working, and If I remove Animation then the script starts working again.

PS: I'm a beginner at Unity. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

DetermineAim Code:

```
void DetermineAim()
{
    Vector3 target = normalLocalPosition;

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        target = aimLocalPosition;
    }
    Vector3 desiredPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, target, Time.deltaTime * aimSmoothing);

    transform.localPosition = desiredPosition;

}
```

What Method does:
[image]
So as soon as add Idle animation to it stop working. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Animator is one of the last things applied during a frame -> as soon as any state holds one single key frame on a certain property then the animator will always overwrite whatever you do in code. You could separate it though into two objects (parent and child) and animate either only the parent and then move the child via code or the other way round

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just created the parent empty object applied animations to that and it worked :) Thanks!